# Cómo dejo al medio un svg en mi navbar

Tags: html, css, nodejs

Hola tengo este código pero no puedo lograr que quede centrado el svg, este lo ocupara mostrar un dropdown de bootstrap 5 para logearse.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<p class="dropdown-toggle user-action removecaret" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon-tabler icon-tabler-login"
                         width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 10 32" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                        <path d="M14 8v-2a2 2 0 0 0 -2 -2h-7a2 2 0 0 0 -2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h7a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2v-2"></path>
                        <path d="M20 12h-13l3 -3m0 6l-3 -3"></path>
                    </svg>
                    </p>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                        <a href="/login" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>LogIn</a>
                        <a href="/register" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>Register</a>
                    </div>
```

Ese es el código que uso

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que revisar la propiedad [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) del svg, en este ejemplo está con los valores "6 -4 10 32":

```css
svg{border: 1px solid red;}/* Es solo para ver el contenedor */

.dropdown-menu, p{ max-width: 100px; text-align: center;} /* Es solo para que se vea centrado*/
```

```html
<p class="dropdown-toggle user-action removecaret" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon-tabler icon-tabler-login"
                         width="64" height="64" viewBox="6 -4 10 32" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                        <path d="M14 8v-2a2 2 0 0 0 -2 -2h-7a2 2 0 0 0 -2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h7a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2v-2"></path>
                        <path d="M20 12h-13l3 -3m0 6l-3 -3"></path>
                    </svg>
                    </p>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                        <a href="/login" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>LogIn</a>
                        <a href="/register" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>Register</a>
                    </div>
```